# Controlling width of geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Consider this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- c(1,0,1,1,0)
qplot( as.factor(data) ) + 
  geom_bar(width=1) + 
  labs(x="Merged", y="Count")
```

I can control the width to a certain degree, e.g. 1 < 2 < 3. However, when I try to go below 1 the bars don't seem to get any thinner. Hence I ask a) is there a lower limit to the width of geom_bar, and b) can I make the bars thinner in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work with `qplot`. If you just use `ggplot`, it works:

```
ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(as.factor(data))) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.1)
```

[image]